# VBscript process disappears

Tags: process, vbscript

A few days ago I first noticed that one of my VBscripts just stopped by itself, a few seconds after starting. Turns out that the wscript.exe process gets killed off about 5 seconds after it is created. This is pretty exact. I wrote a test script with:

> wscript.sleep 4800
>   wscript.echo "hi"

I see the wscript.exe process in TaskManager, I will see the message box for a split second after waiting 4.8 sec. and then it (and the process) disappears. Changing the time to 5200 and I will never see a message box.
And here the strange thing: setting the time to 5000, the process will also be killed most of the time, but I've witnessed 3 times that is was not killed. The process would not disappear until I clicked OK.

- Same behavior for wscript.exe and cscript.exe
- Double clicking the vbs from Explorer, or running the vbs from a administrator-started cmd.exe makes no difference
- I'm using Security Essentials (and have for a long time)
- HijackThis shows this line (that has not always been there): O4 - HKLM..\RunOnce: [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware] C:\Program Files (x86)\Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware\mbamgui.exe /install /silent
  (mbamgui.exe is not a running process though)
- When run with cscript output is:

> d:\temp>cscript tst.vbs
>   Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> hi
>   Script execution time was exceeded on script "d:\temp\tst.vbs".
>   Script execution was terminated.

The code below also only shows a result if the calculation time is kept below 5 seconds:

> t1=Timer
>   For i=1 to 25000000
>   x = Rnd()*Rnd()
>   Next
>   MsgBox timer-t1

On my machine, with 25000000 I see the result a split second, with 30000000 the result is never shown.

Is there any way to pinpoint which process is responsible for killing my VBscript process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout default is none, so maybe you've accidentally configured a [timeout for the script engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490816.aspx).

If that's not the issue, than you can try to monitor the scripting process (either WScript or CScript) using [Sysinternals ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/he-il/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: there is a command line option `//S` which will "set the current command line options for the user". I have not tested this but it implies that if run at the same time as the `//T` (timeout) option, it will store the T option as a default

Comment: Yes, that was it. I've just tested //T with //S and it is stored in the Timeout REG-DWORD under [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings]. I have it fact been playing around with these //options not so long ago....

Comment: The mystery of the thing I witnessed three times remains though....